# Setting the manager property in AD without knowing the manager's URL

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, ldap

I have a function that will allow me to edit the manager property of a user here:

```
 Public Shared Sub SetManagerProperty(ByVal de As DirectoryEntry, ByVal pName As String, ByVal pValue As String)


        'First make sure the property value isnt "nothing"
        If Not pValue Is Nothing Then
            'Check to see if the DirectoryEntry contains this property already
            If de.Properties.Contains(pName) Then   'The DE contains this property
                'Update the properties value
                de.Properties(pName)(0) = pValue
            Else    'Property doesnt exist
                'Add the property and set it's value

                'de.Properties(pName).Add("cn=" & frmOrganization.txtManagerName.Text & ",OU=Company,OU=Users,OU=Summit,OU=North America,DC=mycompany,DC=com")


            End If
        End If

    End Sub
```

But what if the manager is not in the Company OU?  How can I edit this to search for him in the entire domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `DirectorySearcher` object

```
DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher();
ds.SearchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(String.Format("LDAP://{0}/{1}",adserver,searchroot));
ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
ds.Filter = String.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", frmOrganization.txtManagerName.Text);
SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
if (sr == null)
{
    // Manager does not exist
    return null;
}
String managerDN = sr.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
```

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't seem to like converting the SearchResult to a string. I receive an unspecified error.

Comment: Are you converting the search result or the properties?  Also, if you are more comfortable working with DirectoryEntries, you can also use the SearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry() option